# ayuda con Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Soy nuevo en el ámbito de la programación y estoy aprendiendo Django y Python a la vez. quiero  crear una base de datos con tres tablas. proyecto, piezas y procesos. un proyecto puede tener varias piezas, pero una pieza no puede pertenecer a varios proyectos. la tabla pieza puede tener varios procesos.

En mi archivo `models.py` cree las siguientes clases/modelos:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Proyecto(models.Model):
    PO = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    fechaInicio = models.DateTimeField()
    fechaTerminacion = models.DateTimeField()
    observaciones = models.TextField(max_length=500)


class Pieza(models.Model):
    PO = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    noPlano = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    responsable = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    procesos = models.ForeignKey(Procesos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Procesos(models.Model):
    noPlano = models.ForeignKey(Pieza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    corte = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    escuadre = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    maquinado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rectificado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pulido = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Y tengo los siguientes problemas en a clase `Piezas`  me encuentro un error con el campo  `procesos

```
procesos = models.ForeignKey(Procesos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NameError: name 'Procesos' is not defined
```

---

**Pregunta adicional:**

Como puedo hacer que la tabla de `Procesos` sea disponible para la tabla piezas? la idea es que en mi template pueda desplegar una lista de piezas pertenecientes a un mismo proyecto y que muestre los procesos que cada pieza tiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te da error porque en **Piezas** cuando haces alusión a **Procesos**, esta última clase todavía no se ha declarado, pues está después.

Entre Piezas y Procesos tienes una relación Muchos a Muchos si no me equivoco. Pues bien, no puedes tener un ForeignKey en Procesos hacia Piezas y otro ForeignKey en Piezas hacia procesos. Eso en Django se resolvería así:

```
class Pieza(models.Model):
    PO = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    noPlano = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    responsable = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Procesos(models.Model):
    noPlano = models.ManyToManyField(Pieza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    corte = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    escuadre = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    maquinado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rectificado = models.BooleanField(default=False
```

De esta manera **noPlano** es una lista de Piezas.